# How can I display the value inside foreach loop

Tags: php, foreach, slim

How can I get the value inside the **foreach** loop? I am stuck in code.
To make it short, here's my code:

```
    $students = $this->db->table('sys_user')
    ->select(['*'])
    ->leftjoin('sys_user_student', 'sys_user_student.user_id', '=', 'sys_user.user_id')
    ->leftjoin('sys_mf_section', 'sys_mf_section.section_id', '=',
               'sys_user_student.section_id')
    ->leftjoin('sys_mf_grade', 'sys_mf_grade.grade_id', '=', 'sys_mf_section.grade_id')
    ->where('sys_user.user_type_id', '4')
    ->where('sys_mf_section.section_id', $request->getParam('section_id'))
    ->where('sys_mf_grade.grade_id', $request->getParam('grade_id'))
    ->get()->toArray();     

    $result = array();
    foreach ($students as $key => $value) {
        $user_id = $value->user_id;

        $logs = $this->db->table('sys_user')
        ->where('user_id', $user_id)
        ->get()->toArray();

        $result[] = $logs;
    }
```

here's the `view` file. By the way, im using `twig` as my template engine

```
            <tbody>
            {% for student in students %}
            <tr>
                <td class="t-center">{{ student.identification_number }}</td>
                <td class="t-center">{{ student.last_name }}, {{ student.first_name }}</td>
                <td class="t-center">{{ student.gender }}</td>
                {% for results in result %}
                    <td class="t-center">{{ results.tapped_time | date('h:i:s A') }}</td>
                {% endfor %}
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
            {% if students is empty %}
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4">No Data</td>
            </tr>
            {% endif %}
        </tbody>
```

Comment: Have U tried to print_r or var_dump it?

Comment: yes i dump it, and it has value, but when i put it to the view, it gives me null

Comment: put it to the view? What does that mean? You are going to need to show more code

Comment: Have U passed students array to twig template?
Like in twig exapmle: echo $template->render(array('the' => 'variables', 'go' => 'here'));

Comment: @tiacocstoe, yes i passed it the twig template already

Comment: to get things straight - you get <tr>
                <td colspan="4">No Data</td>
            </tr> as a result?

Comment: or U just have problem with result?

Comment: if with the result my answer below is still correct, but not the twig suntax ( had no idea U use twig while writing it ). Have a sekond of tjinking about my anbswer and U should get it :)

Comment: i have problem to the result, i don't know why it does'nt give the correct data, but i var_dump-ed it, it has a value.

Comment: because result is an array of arrays

Comment: @tiacocstoe so there's no chance that i can view it?

Comment: I've modified my answer, hope You get it. That's one way to do this :) Another ( worst ) is in my comment to that answer

Comment: Awaiting upvote buddy :)

Answer (score -1):

You ( as a result ) have array of array, something like 
[['name'=>value, 'name2'=>value2], ['name'=>value, 'name2'=>value2]]
So You have to use 2 foreach loops to see results

```
foreach ($results as $index=>$array){
 foreach ($array as $k=>$v){
   echo $k." = ".$v."<br>";
 }
}
```

Second answer ( proper ) :

```
foreach ($students as $key => $value) {
        $user_id = $value->user_id;

        $logs = $this->db->table('sys_user')
        ->where('user_id', $user_id)
        ->get()->toArray();
         foreach ($logs as $l){
             $result[] = $l;
          }
    }
```

Think about making it like this in another step:

```
foreach ($logs as $l){
                 $result[$user_id][] = $l;
              }
```

Comment: Please read this answer it's correct

Comment: {% for results in result %}
{% for results123 in results %}
                    <td class="t-center">{{ results123 .tapped_time | date('h:i:s A') }}</td>
                {% endfor %}
                {% endfor %}

Comment: obviously the best way would be to modify php with array_merge, and one logical thing is tjhat You get all the results, but You should get them by a user id